# Whats the best database for iphone apps

Tags: ios, database

i just started coding iPhone apps on xcode and i was curious what is the best database to use? For example a database to store names emails etc, to make a sign up and login page.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you said the words "sign up and login page," I suppose you are talking about an online database.

Use Parse.com's BaaS (backend as a service). Its also super easy to implement. [Here](https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views) is a tutorial from them talking about how to make a sign in/sign up page.

Keep in mind, there are other Baas like Kinvey and StorageRoom which are also good as well.

Comment: Yes im trying to store information about the user, for example username and password so they can login etc. When i messed around in PHP i used mySQL as a database, so i was trying to find a equivalent in ios apps.

Comment: Yeah then this is what I think you are looking for.

Comment: Not quite SQL but simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about storing a database local to your device, coredata is the standard: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdProgrammingGuide.html

Small amounts of data can be persisted using user defaults: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: user defaults couldn't be easier to use: 'NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [defaults setObject:mostRecentAssetDate forKey:@"mostRecentAssetDate"];'